# Add +1 if cell above is different

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to find a formula or VBA code for the following scenario:

I have a set of data where numbers in column B appear like this:

```
2000228
2000228
2000228
2000228
2000230
2000230
2000230
2000230
2000232
2000232
2000232
```

I would like to have column A populated with "1" for the first 4 rows and then add +1 each time the numbers are changing, meaning it would "2" for the next 4 and "3" for the next 3 and so on.

I know there is a formula or VBA for this i found it before but cant think of it now how i search for it.

Answer (score 1):

Can try-

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE($A$1:$A1))
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to know. If it helps then please mark the answer as accepted (tick mark the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Although [Harun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5514747/harun24hr)'s answer is correct, hereby an answer which is more in line with the way you ask your question. The whole idea is based on the formula `=IF(A3=A2,B2,B2+1)`, hereby a screenshot:

[image]

The formula means: if the left cell equals the left above cell, just copy the value above, otherwise add 1 (which is in fact what you asked for :-) ).